# Javascript hide & show div to enter password

Tags: javascript

I have a hidden div element, that includes an input for a password, if an user clicks the button for a private session.

Only the part of my function, where it does show the hidden put works. Reversed, the other way around, it is not hiding the shown input after another click on the button (using bootstrap with Laravel btw).

"password button trigger"

```js
function passwordCreator(id) {
  if (document.getElementById(id).style.visibility = 'hidden') {
      document.getElementById(id).style.visibility = 'visible';
  }else if(document.getElementById(id).style.visibility = 'visible') {
      document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="custom-control custom-switch" onclick="passwordCreator('enterPassword')">
    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customSwitch1">
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="customSwitch1">Private Session?</label>
</div>

<div class="input-group" style="visibility:hidden" id="enterPassword">
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <span class="input-group-text" id="">Passwort</span>
    </div>
    <input type="password" class="form-control">
</div>
```

Did not work either. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got a couple of minor issues with your code.

**Issue 1: Equality Checking**

The first is that you are using a single `=` for equality checking.  You should be using a double-equals `==`, as a single indicates assignment (so you reassign the value of `visibility` instead of evaluating it):

```
if (document.getElementById(id).style.visibility = 'hidden') {
```

Should be (notice double `=`):

```
if (document.getElementById(id).style.visibility == 'hidden') {
```

**Issue 2: Using Display**

The second issue is using `display = 'none'`.  You just need to set the `visibilitiy` back to `visible`:

```
document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none';
```

Should be:

```
document.getElementById(id).style.visibility = 'hidden';
```

**Issue 3: Use OnChange not OnClick**

Finally, your `onclick` code is firing twice.  Rather than using `onclick` on the `div`, just use `onchange` on the `checkbox` itself, which only fires when the check changes:

```
<div class="custom-control custom-switch" onclick="passwordCreator('enterPassword')">
    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customSwitch1">
```

Should be:

```
<div class="custom-control custom-switch">
    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customSwitch1"
```

**Working Code**

Here's the working code:

```js
function passwordCreator(id) {
  if (document.getElementById(id).style.visibility == 'hidden') {
    document.getElementById(id).style.visibility = 'visible';
  } else if(document.getElementById(id).style.visibility == 'visible') {
    document.getElementById(id).style.visibility = 'hidden';
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="custom-control custom-switch">
  <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customSwitch1" onchange="passwordCreator('enterPassword');">
  <label class="custom-control-label" for="customSwitch1">Private Session?</label>
</div>

<div class="input-group" style="visibility:hidden" id="enterPassword">
  <div class="input-group-prepend">
    <span class="input-group-text" id="">Passwort</span>
  </div>
  <input type="password" class="form-control">
</div>
```

Comment: I managed to use the first commenter's code in order to work out, but I also tried your solution. Cleaner & shorter!

Answer (score 1):

You are not comparing your string correctly, there is only one `=`, this is assigning value rather than comparing them.

Also, when setting the `visibility` property to `'visible'` you are never removing the `display:none`. Samething when adding the `display:none` property, you are never changing the visibility. So it passes in your code only one time.

```js
function passwordCreator(id) {
  if (document.getElementById(id).style.visibility == 'hidden') {
      document.getElementById(id).style.visibility = 'visible';
      document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'unset';
  }else if(document.getElementById(id).style.visibility == 'visible') {
      document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none';
      document.getElementById(id).style.visibility = 'hidden';
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="custom-control custom-switch" onclick="passwordCreator('enterPassword')">
    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customSwitch1">
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="customSwitch1">Private Session?</label>
</div>

<div class="input-group" style="visibility:hidden" id="enterPassword">
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <span class="input-group-text" id="">Passwort</span>
    </div>
    <input type="password" class="form-control">
</div>
```

**P.S.**
Changing the value of the checkbox using the label will not trigger the `onclick` event. You might want to change it to listen to another event instead.

Comment: Worked perfectly, I wrapped everything in another div & now it works like I wanted. Thanks!